# CouchDB replication error: random fail with error "checkpoint_commit_failure"

Tags: couchdb

Inside a PHP application I'm trying to replicate 4 DBs in and out: this is **only** happening with one of those replications: database's name is "people". To avoid any PHP library specific issue, I'm testing from bash running curl:

**curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST LOCAL_PATH/_replicate -d '{"source":"REMOTE_PATH/people","target":"LOCAL_PATH/people", "continuous":false}'**

With this output:

**{"error":"checkpoint_commit_failure","reason":"Error updating the source checkpoint document: conflict"}**

I've checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647998/couchdb-checkpoint-commit-failure), but it doesn't seem to be that, as we're using full paths for replication (both local and remote).

This happens most of the times, but not always.. Any idea???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB stores check points in the source database server for the last sequence id it was able to replicate. Therefore the credentials that you're using to replicate from the source server with also need write permission on the source database to write these check points.

However, this is not strictly necessary because **check points are an optimization**. Your docs will replicate just fine without these check points.

Comment: Thanks Sam! I've created a new user:pass in the local CouchDB that matches the one in the main CouchDB, and it started working :)

Comment: Sam, somehow this is happening again. I'm replicating between the local and remote with the same user and pass, both set up as admins. The only thing that's changed is that the server has Basic Auth. Is there any way we can "disable" check points and see if that fixes the problem? Thanks!